# Auto-increment vs manual incrementing in SQL

Tags: sql, auto-increment

I'm not a database expert, but I'm curious about auto-incrementing in SQL.
Is it efficient, a friend of mine, his opinions, he's not using auto-incrementing instead he's taking the last id every time he insert something. I'm in doubt whether to use his ideas, which I guess is less efficient or go with auto-incrementing provided by the database itself.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Regardless unless you have a very very good reason, use auto-increment.

Comment: Autoincreqment or sequence will always be faster. When doing this your self, you can only do this in isolation level serializable. Otherwise you may have duplicate numbers.

Comment: "a friend of mine, his opinions, he's not using auto-incrementing instead he's taking the last id every time he insert something. " - and I bet he's doing it incorrectly!

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes, I don't know what made him think that auto-incrementing isn't efficient. So I searched and ask for answers to avoid that kind of scenario to happen.

Comment: I  have removed all the conflicting tags here. SQL Server has no interaction with PHPMyAdmin (a web based IDE for MySQL) nor MySQLi (a library for interacting with MySQL in PHP).

Comment: "*he's taking the last id every time he insert something*" - there are two ways to implement that anti pattern. Incorrect (this is what most people do) or correct and non-scalable for many concurrent transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use auto-increment every time. It is, by far, the best way to ensure that you have unique values.

If you use the previous highest value, unless you are careful, there is a chance that the same value may be written twice - for example if when two instances of the application retrieve the same previous highest value, add one and insert the new row. (I have seen it happen..)

Both SQL Server and My SQL have built in the auto-increment functionality for a reason. You should only avoid them if you have a specific need for something else.